# New discovery of the unconventional matrix representation for the quaternion $H_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let us start with the notation for the quaternion group  of order 8 as $H_8=\{e,i,j,k,g,i^{-1},j^{-1},k^{-1}\}$ where $ij=k=j^{-1}i$, $i^2=j^2=k^2=g$ and $i^4=j^4=k^4=g^2=e$. 
One way to write the 4-by-4 matrix representation of the quaternion as $H_8$ is that

$e=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}, 
i=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
j=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
k=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.$
$$g=i^2=j^2=k^2=-\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}=-e.$$
And we notice that the matrices of $i,j,k$ are skew symmetric. See for example the [Ref: Matrix representation of quaternions
Farebrother-Groß-Troschke](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379502005359) and please check the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Matrix_representations).

> Now let us consider the new notation for the quaternion group  of order 8 as $H_8=\{e,i',j',k',g',i'^{-1},j'^{-1},k'^{-1}\}$. My question is that can we choose the non-skew symmetric matrix representation such that we design and fix the new $$k'=\begin{bmatrix}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
> \end{bmatrix}$$ to be rather unconventional, and notice that the $g'=k'^2$ has a rather unconventional definition
>   $$g'=k'^2=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
> \end{bmatrix},$$ but the identity $$e=(g')^2=i'^4=j'^4=k'^4=\begin{bmatrix}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
> \end{bmatrix}$$ is still the conventional identity matrix $e$.
>
> The **questions** are that does there exist such non-skew symmetric matrix representation of 4-by-4? For the real matrix or the complex matrix?  Given that we restrict the $k'=\begin{bmatrix}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 
> \end{bmatrix}$, what will be the matrix representation form of $i',j'$? (The real matrix or the complex matrix?)

Comment: The matrix $k'$ has eigenvalues $1,-1,i,-i$. Therefore it has to come from a representation with two 1-dimensional components. Thinking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ be a basis for such a representation. We see that $k'$ acts with eigenvalues $\pm1$ on the span $V$ of $v_2,v_3$, and with eigenvalues $\pm i$ on the span $W$ of $v_1,v_4$. This suggests that we should be able to build at least a complex representation with $k'$.

On $V$ we can simply let $j,j^{-1},k,k^{-1}$ all act the same way, and let the subgroup $K=\{1,i,g,i^{-1}\}$ act as the identity. This is the trivial representation of $K$ induced to all of $H_8$, and we only need real matrices to do that.

On $W$ I think we need complex matrices as the resulting representation must be the usual 2-dimensional representation of $H_8$. Putting all these pieces together we end up with

$$
i'=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\bf{i}&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&-\bf{i}\end{array}\right),
\quad
j'=k'i'=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0&0&0&\bf{i}\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
\bf{i}&0&0&0
\end{array}\right).
$$
In the matrices above I used boldface $\bf{i}$ for a complex square root of $-1$. Just to make sure it won't get confused with the quaternion $i\in H_8$ - admittedly there should be no confusion here (but this issue would appear when jotting down elements of the complex group algebra $\Bbb{C}H_8$).

We could equally well induce from $K'=\{1,j,g,j^{-1}\}$ instead of $K$. This would make the matrices $i'$ and $j'$ trade their central 2x2 block (their action on the subspace $V$).

---

Another way of seeing why the 2x2-block giving the action on $W$ (=the corners of the 4x4-matrices) cannot be all reals is that the real span of those matrices must give an algebra isomorphic to the Hamiltonian quaternions. But that algebra cannot be embedded into 2x2 real matrices, because it has real dimension four, hence would have to be all of $M_2(\Bbb{R})$. But that matrix algebra has zero divisors unlike the quaternions, so this is a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice answer! Let me ponder a bit further. I hope your answer is correct.  <3

Comment: This is a very nice answer! ... but it seems like you are using the structure of $$1 \to K=Z/4Z \to H_8 \to Z/2Z \to 1$$. Can you add a small section to illuminate what does this sequence structure help you to find the matrix representation? Especially this unconventional one?

Comment: It is basically the representation of $H_8$ coming from the way it acts on the two cosets of $K$. All the elements of $K$ keep both cosets fixed (because $K\unlhd H_8$), and all the elements not in $K$ interchange the cosets. Therefore the elements of $K$ get $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr}$ in the middle, and the elements not in $K$ get $\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}$. The latter matches with what you wanted there to be in $k'$, and that was the clue.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen, very nice answer, do you have any comment why $i'=\begin{pmatrix}{\mathbf{i}, 0} \\ {0, 1} \end{pmatrix} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} {1, 0}\\ {0, -\mathbf{i}}\end{pmatrix}$ is in tensor product form of 2x2 matrices, but not the others $j',k'$. Is there any particular reasoning for this.

Comment: I don't know. Looks like the restriction of this rep to $K$ can also be written as a tensor product of two 2-dimension reps, but that is not true about the rep of $H_8$ :-)

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen, I am not sure, what do you mean, we can swap $i'$ to $j'$, $j'$ to $k'$. And we can choose different $K$, such as $\{1,i',g,i'^{-1}\}$, $\{1,j',g,j'^{-1}\}$, $\{1,k',g,k'^{-1}\}$. Are you making the some of the element more special than the others? Could you just swap $i'$ to $j'$, $j'$ to $k'$?

Comment: I meant that we can also use
$$i'=\pmatrix{i&0&0&0\cr0&0&1&0\cr0&1&0&0\cr0&0&0&-i\cr}$$ and
$$j'=\pmatrix{0&0&0&i\cr0&1&0&0\cr0&0&1&0\cr i&0&0&0\cr}.$$ They swapped their central 2x2 blocks. We cannot change $k'$ because you gave that already, so it will act on the subspace $V$ with eigenvalues $\pm 1$. The question is which of $i'$ or $j'$ will act on $V$ as identity, and we can choose either way. Note that because $V$ is to be a sum of 1-dimensional reps of $H_8$, $g$ will always act as identity on $V$.

Comment: Hi Jyrki, can we interpret your new $i',j',k'$ in terms of some matrix $U$ transformation, such that $i'=U i U^{-1}$, $j'=U j U^{-1}$,  $k'=U k U^{-1}$, perhaps $U$ can be unitary? If not, can one do something like the Schur decomposition? Many thanks!

Comment: @ Jyrki, Also, is it possible to make the 4 by 4 matrix representation in "real" number? Thank you.